Internet is slow on Macbook when tethered to my iPhone
Background:

M1 Macbook Pro Running Sonoma 14.5
iPhone 14 Pro Running iOS 17.5.1
T-Mobile in the USA

I called T-Mobile and they have confirmed that I have no data restrictions on tethering.
I have tried tethering with USB, Bluetooth, and Wifi.
Maximize Compatibility is off.
The tethered internet speed has been slow since I purchased my iPhone last year. I made a Genius Bar appointment, and we discovered it was not my MacBook.  We connected to a iPhone in the store and got reasonable internet speeds. Unfortunately, T-Mobile has a dead zone in the store so we couldn't test a T-Mobile device (including my phone.)
We reset the network setting on my iPhone and he said go into the parking lot and try it.
When I did a speed test from my phone I got 600mb down. When I connected to my hotspot using my Mac I got 1mb down.
The next step that Apple suggested was to reset my iPhone to the factory settings. I am reluctant to do that before I exhaust all other options.
